# Alternative ways to use User-defined type guards?

Tags: typescript

I'm reading about User-Defined Type Guards in the Typescript handbook. Say you have a union type that you want to narrow down as follows:

```
interface Bird{
    fly();
    layEggs();
}

interface Fish{
    swim();
    layEggs();
}

class SmallPet implements Fish,Bird{
    constructor(){
    }
    fly() { console.log("fly")};
    swim() { console.log("swim")};
    layEggs() {console.log("laying eggs") };
}

function getSmallPet(): Fish | Bird{
    return new SmallPet();
}

function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish{
    return (<Fish>pet).swim !== undefined;
}

let pet = getSmallPet();

if (isFish(pet))
    pet.swim(); //works
```

The function isFish is a User-Defined Type Guard as mentioned in the handbook. My question is how does this work? I tried to achieve the same result in a more sloppy way, which wasn't obviously going to work:

```
pet is Fish;
pet.swim(); //doesn't work
```

Does Typescript have to parse a function that looks like a type guard to achieve this feature and subsequently narrow down the type with the function call? Is there no other way to have type guards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User defined type guards have two functions:

1. Check at runtime whether a value is of a certain type
2. Tell the compiler that a value is of a certain type

If you know that your instance is of type `Fish` then you can simply:

```
(pet as Fish).swim();
```

And in your case you can also use the `instanceof` type guard:

```
if (pet instanceof SmallPet) {
    pet.swim();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) says

> A type guard is some expression that performs a runtime check that guarantees the type in some scope.

So when you use a type guard, the type checker will narrow the type of the instance for the current scope: the if block in this case

The same operation could be done using `pet instanceof Fish` in the if statement. The type checker does the same kind of narrowing for the current scope.